# NLog: Using WithHeader property in MemoryTarget with CsvLayout

Tags: c#, csv, nlog

I'm using c# + NLog and try to write to a **MemoryTarget**. I have the folloowing config:

```
        MemoryTarget = new MemoryTarget();

        CsvLayout csvLayout = new CsvLayout() { Delimiter = CsvColumnDelimiterMode.Comma, WithHeader = true };

        csvLayout.Columns.Add(new CsvColumn() { Name = "Name", Layout = "${event-context:item=Name}" });
        csvLayout.Columns.Add(new CsvColumn() { Name = "AuditTimeStamp", Layout = "${event-context:item=AuditTimeStamp}" });

        MemoryTarget.Layout = csvLayout;
```

(MemoryTarget is of course a NLog.MemoryTarget property)

So when I log stuff I can access the MemoryTarget via

```
MemoryTarget.Logs
```

**What I don't get:** also I have configured the **WithHeader** property in my CsvLayout I don't see a header in my MemoryTarget.Logs. I'd expect **Name, AuditStamp** in MemoryTarget.Logs[0] but it starts with the logged content right away.

**Can anybody tell my why the header is not part of the MemoryTarget.Logs list?**

Comment: I don't know, but the header ehaves buggy in some circumstances, e.g. with the arhcive otion. The first file ge's the header, but all other files not. So maybe the same bug affects your program...

Comment: Interesting. But my MemoryTarget is the first 'file', I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers (and footers) only used by targets derevived from `TargetWithLayoutHeaderAndFooter`

Because the `MemoryTarget` is deriving from the `TargetWithLayout` and not from the `TargetWithLayoutHeaderAndFooter` setting the `WithHeader = true` does not have any effect on the the `MemoryTarget`. So you cannot get the header in `MemoryTarget.Logs`.

In order to the header outputted correctly you need to use one of targets which supports it:

- Console
- Colored Console
- File
- Mail
- Debugger

Or you can directly access the generated header in your code with the help of `LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent()` and calling:

```
string header = ((CsvLayout)MemoryTarget.Layout).Header
    .Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
```

Comment: Wow, amazing answer. I wouldn't ever have figured that out by myself. Thank you!